# Why is it when "this" is a pointer to const, the return type has to be a constant reference and not a simple reference?

Tags: c++, function, class

I'm studying classes currently and struggling to understand why when a member function is const the return type cannot be a simple reference and has to be a constant reference. The problem is related to the line of code below. If I were to remove const from the return type I get a compiler error.

I've tried to reread the section several times but don't understand what exactly is causing this to be an error and why it is necessary for it to be a constant reference when the member function is constant.

```
class Person{
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    const std::string& getname() const {return name;}
};
```

Comment: What do you consider a const  `*this` means?

Comment: If you (the object) are `const` how would it make sense to return a modifiable reference to yourself? `const` means you cannot be modified.

Comment: If you need a modifiable return object from a const Person, then return a copy, `std::string getname() const {return name;}` .